# Is there a way for me to "Dynamically" change the "Datasource" of a Dataset using Filehandling?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file-handling, sqldatasource, sqldataadapter

It goes like this, I want to change the Datasource of my C# WPF Application dynamically for me to conveniently run the project from one PC to Another PC since the DataSource of my project is currently under my Laptops name i wanted to somehow run on my Thesis mate's laptop or any other laptops or PC because i cannot bring my own laptop due to technical problems and non-portability issues.

If there is a solution or a different alternative to this i would be glad to hear it

I've heared one time when my classmate implemented their system in a workplace she mentioned that "You should only change the DataSource of your dataset inorder for the project to work on their PC"

the problem is know how to change the DataSourcea inside Visual Studio but all the Potential Laptops and PC i chose to run the project during presentation or Defense doesn't have Visual Studio installed so i wanted my project to have an "External File" to put the DataSource there and Connect my DataBase's DataSource to that "External File"

Comment: I think you should be able to. But you can show specifically in code where you are setting the said data source?

Comment: The DataSource are inside the "Properties" option and there's no code needed for you to change the DataSource

Comment: There most certainly is some code involved somewhere. Dig deeper. Search for something initializing stuff.

Comment: Im using a wizard for my SQL databases and directly create tables inside viual studio all the codes regarding the databases are 90% IDE Generated but when i do actually find it what should i do?

Comment: Search within Properties folder, also look for any .g.cs files. There might be a method somewhere named Initialize() in either your XAML's code behind or application's code behind.